# how do I change the date format on selectDate django widget?

Tags: django, django-widget

I have a date field of a form and I want it to have a format like '21 jan 2020' but I can't find a way to pass it on the selectDate widget

```
class MemoryForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Memory
        fields = ["date"]
        labels = {"date": ""}
        widgets = {
            'date': SelectDateWidget(attrs={"class": "time", "date_format":'%m/%d/%Y'}),
        }
```

I've tried others `attrs` instead of `"date_format":'%m/%d/%Y'` like `"months":'%m'` , or `"months_field":'%m'` but none seemed to work the output was always '21 january 2021'